# Java Compile error when return Generic Class type

Tags: java, class, generics, interface

```
public interface Parent{
}

public class Child implements Parent{
}

public <T extends Parent> Class<T> getClass(){
  return Child.class;  // compile error, add cast to Class<T>
}
```

I expect there is no error about above code, however I get compile error when I return Child.class.

Comment: public Class<? extends Parent> getClass(){ return Child.class; } works. but not understand why the first version does not work.

Comment: You should be using `Class<Child>` if you are always going to return `Child.class`... Use generics only where it makes sense...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't tell Java to always return `Child.class` regardless of `T`. There might be other classes extending from parent that aren't a `Child`. Also, since you are not using `T` anywhere, your code doesn't make much sense. Two possible solutions:

```
public Class<? extends Parent> getAClass() {
    return Child.class;
}
```

or perhaps

```
public <T extends Parent> Class<T> getAClass(Class<T> clazz){
    return clazz; 
}
```

The second example compiles, but would probably make more sense if `T` was declared at class level.

Also, I renamed your method to avoid a name clash with the existing `getClass()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Review the following

```
public class Main {
    public interface Parent{}
    public class Child implements Parent{}        
    public class BadChild implements Parent {}

    public static <T extends Parent> Class<T> getClazz() {
        return Child.class;  // compile error, add cast to Class<T>
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<BadChild> clazz = Main.<BadChild>getClazz();
    }
}
```

Calling method `getClazz()` with `BadChild` type is valid for the caller side. If you could compile your method that would lead to runtime errors. That's why this is forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

If this code were legal, it would be possible to write:

```
Class<SomeOtherChildClass> clazz = instance.getAClass();
```

(assuming `SomeOtherChildClass` also extends `Parent`) which would clearly fail at runtime for the existing implementation.

I offer no "corrected" code because I am not sure what you are trying to do.